# MVC4 De/Serialization with JSON / JSON.NET - List<BaseClass> and derived types inside

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, list, serialization, derived

I am trying to do some basic communication with MVC4 Controllers over JSON.
I need to send and receive data at both points. For the client am using RestSharp.

My Problem is, that the List of TheObjectIWantToTransfer has no values, when it is transmitted to the server.
Thats why i started playing around with Json.NET on the controller side as well.

These are example class, how the stuff looks like i want to transfer.

```
public class TheObjectIWantToTransfer
{
    public int JustAGeneralNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
    public List<MyBaseType> Data { get; set; }

    public TheObjectIWantToTransfer()
    {
        Data = new List<MyBaseType>();
    }
}

// class of the list

[KnownType(typeof(MyDerivedTypeA))]
[KnownType(typeof(MyDerivedTypeB))]
public abstract class MyBaseType
{
    public string SomeGeneralStuff { get; set; }
}

public class MyDerivedTypeA : MyBaseType
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

public class MyDerivedTypeB : MyBaseType
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public string IamYourFather { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried using the

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All};
```

with JsonConvert Serialize/Deserialize. The output changed, but i still didn't got it working. He was unable to find the referenced types, and i have no idea how to receive a
TypeNameHandling.All Json.NET Object at a Controller.
I have created the JsonNetResult which gives me the possibility to serialize with TypeNameHandling.All and send the data to the client. But i can't receive/deserialize with Json.NET?

```
 public JsonNetResult MyAction(MyClassType blub)
 {
     // blub ?? is beeing deserialized by the default JSON deserializer of MVC.
 }
```

I just need a solution. I Would be happy to keep the normal Json() method of MVC if this is possible.

I can't believe its not working with derived types in an array. There must be some kind attribute or hack to activate this.

Or i am doing something crazy really really wrong..

Thx !

Comment: There seems to be a bug in Silverlight.
In a normal console app, serialization->deserialization works like a charm in "All" mode. The exact same code in silverlight results in this exception "Error resolving type specified in JSON". It has an inner exception of type System.IO.FileLoadException: can not find assembly of type bla...   seems to be a silverlight specific JSON.NET bug. is there a way to use something else?

Comment: Silverlight 5, Json.NET version 4.0.8